# How to raycasting to player facing direction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

in my 2D topdown game, I'm trying to cast a ray from my player to the direction he is facing. all going great yet the problem is the moment the player stop moving the raycast stopped(which makes sense I'm using Input.GetAxis which returns value of 0 when stop moving). I've been trying using Transform.right / TransformDirection its just makes the ray to stick at the same position and not where the player facing. is there any way for me to keep the ray cast keep going even if my player is stop moving?

```css
    public Collider2D GetBarrleCollider()
    {

        Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(this.transform.position, movement, playerDistance);
        if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickup"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Return NOT null" + " " + hit.collider.tag);
            return hit.collider;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Return null");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```css
public void MovementHandler()
    {

            movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + movement * getPlayerMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
  }
```

Comment: you do not show under what conditions the raycasting is done and the relation with the  Input.GetAxis where the problems seems to be. I would show all of the code where the problem might be

Comment: Move the raycasting code to outside of the GetAxis.. condition.  transform.forward will give you the direction the player is facing.

Comment: Just updating What I did that made the script to work. it that i needed to make sure that the last direction had been saved as a vector 2, so i just made a new vector 2 and saved there the current movement direction, there for the player know where to look all time 
If(movement != Vector2.Zero){
faceDirection = movement;
}

Answer (score 1):

You would store the direction as a variable. Lets call it `lookDir`. Then you should check if the movement vector is not zero:

```
Vector2 lookDir;

public void MovementHandler()
{
    movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + movement * getPlayerMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (movement != Vector2.zero)
    {
        lookDir = movement;
    }
}
```

---

Then you could raycast from this vector. This way, you only change it if the player is moving.

Something like this should work:

```
public void MovementHandler()
{
    movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    rb2D.MovePosition(rb2D.position + movement * getPlayerMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (movement != Vector2.zero)
    {
        lookDir = movement;
    }
}
public Collider2D GetBarrleCollider()
{
    Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;

    //this line was changed \/
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(this.transform.position, lookDir, playerDistance);
    //

    if (hit.collider != null && hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Pickup"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Return NOT null" + " " + hit.collider.tag);
        return hit.collider;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Return null");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Let me know in the comments if this doesn't work.

Comment: thnx for the replay. this is exactly what I did and i already update in the comments for it :) thnx ! might help other :)